# Problem with running hangfire dashboard on .net 5 web api

Tags: c#, .net, .net-5, hangfire

I installed and configure hangfire on my .net 5 solution

In ConfigureServices i have :

```
services.AddHangfire(x => x.UseSqlServerStorage(configRoot["ConnectionString:Prod"]));
```

And on Configure :

```
         app.UseHangfireDashboard("/hangfire", new DashboardOptions
        {
            AppPath = null,
            DashboardTitle = "Hangfire Dashboard"
        });
        app.UseHangfireServer();
```

Once the solution running it give me that

[Attached Picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FgIkQ.png)

Any solution ?

Comment: Have you tried it with http?

Comment: I resolved by adding an option at startup.cs, isApiOnly = false